# Создание list для каждого чата

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, list

У меня проблема: есть чат бот в вк, и в нём надо создать list для каждой беседы. Пробовал так:

```
globals()[str(chat_id)] = []
```

Но так ничего не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `globals` не надо, лучше создайте словарь и храните все там

```
chats = {}
chats[chat_id] = []
```

Что-бы производить какие либо действия над объектом писать надо так

```
chats[chat_id].append("что нибудь")
```